# Prevent element from returning to original position after keyframe animation

Tags: angularjs, animation, addclass, css-animations

I am trying out Dan Eden's [animation.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in my angular app.

I have a custom directive which uses angular's $animate service to add CSS classes to my element.

Example:

**CSS**

```
.bounce-add.bounce-add-active {
    -webkit-animation: bounceOutLeft 2.5s;
    animation: bounceOutLeft 2.5s;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div my-directive="action"/>
```

**JS**

```
myMod.directive("myDirective", function ($animate) {

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch('myDirective', function (value, oldValue) {
            // if( value == doBounce ) 
            $animate.addClass(element, 'bounce').then(function () {
      });
}

return {
    link: linker,
    scope: {
        'myDirective': '=',
    },
  };
});
```

Here the bounce out left animation appears when I expect it to, however my element then returns back to it's original position.

I have tried animation-fill-mode: forwards with no luck. I have also tried adding an extra CSS class since angular removes the class after the animation is finished, so instead of `.bounce-add.bounce-add-active` I have `.bounce.bounce-add.bounce-add-active` along with `class="bounce"` in my html.

Is there a way to keep elements at their final position after using a CSS style containing a key frame animation using the $animate service's addClass?

[Here is the Plunker example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/svl4PNBVaSu5YYpj9qE3)

Comment: AngularJS version? I tested and `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` worked fine. But do you really want your element to remain at its final state? It will be like 2000px off to the left. Do you want it visible out there or do you just want to hide it?

Comment: Angular Version is 1.3. Yes I want it to stay there and then I will perform another animation from that point via the callback.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a Plunker example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the animation to the class you are adding and use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`:

```
.bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounceOutRight 2.5s;
  -moz-webkit-animation: bounceOutRight 2.5s;
  animation: bounceOutRight 2.5s;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/j8MtQvvF7cBtTLwE2sFc?p=preview

Comment: Wow - I had tried this but had placed the animation-fill-mode's *before* the animation and this did not work. Thanks!