# Angular increment animation doesn't stay in last position

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

Im trying to trigger animation when the value of `countAllOrders` changes. Specifically, im trying to set the margin of list using keyframs in angular animation. My html is as follows:

```
  <ul class="digits" [@ordersValue]="countAllOrders" #digits>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>{{ countAllOrders }}</li>
  </ul>
```

and the animation implementtation is:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('ordersValue', [
      transition(':increment', [
        animate('1s', keyframes([style({ marginTop: '-7em' })])),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

the initial css of `.digits` sets `margin-top:0em` . during animation the desired effect works but instead of finishig with margin top's value to be `-7em` it ends with `0em`.
According to some answers I found here I tried to use state

```
trigger('ordersValue', [
  state(':increment', style({ marginTop: '-7em' })),
  transition(':increment', [
    style({ marginTop: '-7em' }),
    animate('1s', style('*')),
  ]),
]),
```

css:

```
.digits {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0em;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

but that didnt help, any idea how to tackle this one?

Comment: Add style `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to your `.digits` class.

Comment: Edited my post, I did have the property set but it doesnt help

Comment: `animation-fill-mode` works when you set animation in style. You made animation in your javascript, so you it doesn't work. you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049799/angular-4-keyframe-animation-stay-on-last-position)

Comment: And also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078911/prevent-element-from-returning-to-original-position-after-keyframe-animation).

Comment: Do you have animation name?

Comment: If so, add `animation-name: xxx`. it would work.

Comment: you mean add it in the javacript or css?. not sure I understood your answer. `animation-fill-mode: forwards` was set in my *.css file and not in the javascript

Comment: Yes, but no `animatin-name` in your css file. So it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if in the keyframe you need to have a `from` marginTop: '0' and `to` marginTop: '-7em'?

Here is a link which might help : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Just add the last line `animation-fill-mode:forwards;` and remove the `infinite` at the end of the second last line.

```
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```